# What does it mean that Android Studio has appended the word "dirty" into my release apk name?

Tags: android, apk

As per the title, I have just built a release apk for my app and Android Studio has appended `-dirty.apk` to the file name.

So now I have `myapp-v1-dirty.apk`

What does this mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I now realise it's because there are changes that have not been committed at the time that the release apk was built.